# How to get specific object values from all child location in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

In firebase

```
var userRef = http://xx.firebaseio.com/users
```

I can get all the users like

var userAllRecords = $firebase(userRef).$asObject();

and this will give me all the records and I can filter them and get desire values/operations.

But How can I avoid this extra operations specially while working on mobile device apps when I am only interested in one set of records say users balance and name from all users?

So I am looking something like by passing object names in asObject() method. e.g only get user_balance and user_name from all users

e.g: var userAllRecords = $firebase(userRef).$asObject(user_balance, user_name);

I can't find anything that matches here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/

Comment: firebase has just announced the proper way to get specific objects from all child by adding rules 'indexOn' per table/child firebase.com/docs/beta/queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get a subset of collection of nodes in the way you want it. Firebase always retrieves/synchronizes full nodes.

To work around this, you will have to normalize your data structure. You have roughly three options:

1. Create an node with only the `userids` and the "join" in the balance for each user (using `once`)
2. Store the balance for all users in a separate `balances` node
3. Mix the previous two approaches and store the balance both under each user and in a global `balances` node

So if you have this structure now:

```
users
    userid1
        user_name: "Frank van Puffelen"
        user_balance: 15281
    userid2
        user_name: "star18bit"
        user_balance: 1178
```

### Approach 1: keep an index of userids

The data structure becomes:

```
userids
    userid1
    userid2
users
    userid1
        user_name: "Frank van Puffelen"
        user_balance: 15281
    userid2
        user_name: "star18bit"
        user_balance: 1178
```

And then the code something like:

```
var root = new Firebase(FB_URL);
new root.child('userids').on('child_added', function(useridsnapshot) {
  var userid = useridsnapshot.name();
  root.child('users/'+userid+'/user_balance').once('value', function(balancesnapshot) {
      // TODO: do something with balancesnapshot.value();
  }
};
```

### Approach 2: keep the balances globally

The data structure becomes:

```
balances
    userid1: 15281
    userid2: 1178
users
    userid1
        user_name: "Frank van Puffelen"
    userid2
        user_name: "star18bit"
```

And then the code something like:

```
var root = new Firebase(FB_URL);
new root.child(balances).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var userid = snapshot.name();
  var balance = snapshot.val();
};
```

You can probably figure out approach 3 from that.

Comment: I think firebase has just added the proper way to get specific objects from all child by adding rules 'indexOn' per table/child https://www.firebase.com/docs/beta/queries/

Comment: Yup, and it looks quite nice from what I've seen so far. But keep in mind that feature is in beta, so might still change. And you should always prefer a good data structure that matches your needs.